# Error 100013 suddenly appear when try to run video from jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer for my video, yesterday I have started got the following error

[image]

can anyone help please, I did not change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your license key has expired. All the error codes are documented here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/errors-reference/